# Tomcat undeploy/deploy with Ant

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ant, jenkins, undeploy

I have a problem with my ant-script and tomcat. I want to create a ant-scipt who build, compile and deploy my gwt-application on my tomcat-server with jenkins. For this I use the undeploy and deploy task from catalina (catalina-ant.jar). But I get this error:

> BUILD FAILED
>   D:\Jenkins\jobs\HomepageTomcat\workspace\build.xml:124: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ISO_8859_1
>       at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:204)
>       at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask.execute(UndeployTask.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

This are the importend pieces of my ant-script:

```
5 <property name="tomcat.manager.url" value="http://localhost:8080/manager" />
6 <property name="tomcat.manager.username" value="tomcat" />
7 <property name="tomcat-manager-password" value="secret" />
8 <property name="app.name" value="appName" />

116 <target name="tomcat-undeploy" description="undeploy tomcat project">
117  <undeploy
118    url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
119    username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
120    password="${tomcat-manager-password}"
121    path="/${app.name}" 
122  />
123 </target>
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems, your version of `catalina-ant.jar` requires Java 7 and you use a different version. Either use a recent JRE for running Ant or an older `catalina-ant.jar`.

I looked up the code of the current `AbstractCatalinaTask` (see stack trace) and found a reference to `StandardChrasets.ISO_8859_1` at line 204. According to StandardCharsets documentation it did not exist before Java 7.